# Two queries with ORDER BY and UNION - explanation needed

Tags: mysql

I have a table `TestTable`:

```
IntCol
1
4
6
2
3
8
12
11
9
7
15
13
14
```

(numbers are from 1 to 15 excluding 10).

When I do...

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT IntCol
    FROM TestTable
    WHERE IntCol >= 10
    ORDER BY IntCol ASC) x1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT IntCol
    FROM TestTable
    WHERE IntCol < 10
    ORDER BY IntCol DESC) x2
```

... result is ok (first from 11 to 15 ASCending, then from 1 to 9 DECSending):

```
IntCol
11
12
13
14
15
9
8
7
6
4
3
2
1
```

But when I omit `SELECT * FROM` and do...

```
    (SELECT IntCol
    FROM TestTable
    WHERE IntCol >= 10
    ORDER BY IntCol ASC)
UNION ALL
    (SELECT IntCol
    FROM TestTable
    WHERE IntCol < 10
    ORDER BY IntCol DESC)
```

... rows aren't ordered at all (only values greater then 10 are first). The result is:

```
IntCol
12
11
15
13
14
1
4
6
2
3
8
9
7
```

My question is: why there is this `SELECT * FROM` needed when UNIONing ordered rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Individual Queries, cannot have `Order By` clause when there is a union in between them.

for reference

http://p2p.wrox.com/sql-language/17907-union-order.html

here is an example of how Order By is used with Union

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union.php